# first nav to right left

Tags: css

How can I change `other` to right side?

```css
li{
    display: inline;
}
#main{
    float: left;
}
#other{
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<nav id="other">
  <ul>
    <li>other</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<nav id="main">
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This should be like this:

```
one two three other
```

But not like this:

```
one two three             other
```

PS: I cannot change the html.

I know this can be done with absolute positioning but this would be very expensive for responsive design. Thus looking around other solution.

Comment: i don't see any div in your code

Comment: I mean nav here in my example. was struggling to put suitable title.

Comment: As you have Bootstrap tagged, why don't you use a [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) for this?

Comment: I use in my site. But here to keep it simple I just used simple elements that illustrates the key problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way to achieve this is to put into a containing element which is floated left and then float both of the `ul`'s to the right. As `#other` comes first it will be floated right first.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
li {
  display: inline;
}
#main,
#other {
  float: right;
}
div {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <nav id="other">
    <ul>
      <li>other</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav id="main">
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I am so upset with myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `float: left` from your `#other` element and instead set that element's `display` to `inline-block`.

Then to adjust the placement you can remove the `padding-left` from the inner `ul` element and space it apart from the `#main` element with some `margin-left` instead:

```css
li{
  display: inline;
}

#other {
  display: inline-block;
}

#other ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#main{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<nav id="other">
  <ul>
    <li>other</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<nav id="main">
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#main {
  float: left;
}
#other {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="other">
  <ul>
    <li>other</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<nav id="main">
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```